# Visual Studio Report building expression issue

Tags: visual-studio, rdlc

I would like to hear some tips on how to solve my problem.
So, i have Visual Studio report with row groups: Year->Month->Day->Details

[image]

And my report table with all data, it shows data grouped in rows:
[image]

Everything works, but i need to do one thing. In [Hour] row, field/text box [SverT] i have set an working expression for font to change color:

```
=Switch(Fields!SverT.Value = Avg(Fields!SverT.Value, "Day"), "Black",
    Fields!SverT.Value > (Fields!UzdT.Value+5), "Red",
    Fields!SverT.Value < (Fields!UzdT.Value-5), "Red")
```

But i need that upper row [Day] fields [Avg(SverT)] also would change font color if any row in [Hour] have changed color to "Red". How can i do it? What expression to use in that [Avg(SverT)] textbox?

If I have vaguely expressed my problem, if needed, I will try to describe it more clearly.

Comment: Can you duplicate the `hours` expression to the `Day` group instead of checking fields' colour?

Comment: I tried that, but it's not working..